# Помогите вывести значение в localStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Помогите пожалуйста, дописать код, чтобы значения которые выводятся, сохранялись и на других страницах сайтах через localStorage. Сам код:

```
var str = location.search;
if(str.indexOf('city') + 1) {
    document.getElementById('go').innerHTML = 'текст 1';
} else if (str.indexOf('city2') + 1) {
    document.getElementById('go').innerHTML = 'текст 2';
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот добавление данных в localStorage. Первый параметр - ключ, второй - значение.

```
window.localStorage.setItem("city", "текст 1");
window.localStorage.setItem("city2", "текст 2");
```

Для получения данных из хранилища используйте `getItem`:

```
window.localStorage.getItem("city");
```